# Change AppBarLayout theme programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

First I set AppBarLayout theme via xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MyTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyTheme.Toolbar.Title" />
```

where **@style/MyTheme.AppBarOverlay** contains:

```
<style name="MyTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@drawable/toolbar_background</item>
</style>
```

But then in some scenarios I want to change it programmatically without change the Theme of the activity (only the Theme of the AppBarLayout).

I have tried these two ways without success:

1. First:

   ```
   ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
   actionBar.getThemedContext().setTheme(R.style.MyTheme_AppBarOverlay_2);
   ```
2. Second:

   ```
   AppBarLayout mAppBar = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
   mAppBar.getContext().setTheme(R.style.MyTheme_AppBarOverlay_2);
   ```

Comment: Any success on this?

Comment: I have not worked on it, so there are no news.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Changing themes after inflation is not possible with Android views. You'll have to change each property the theme defines individually. You may work around this by using Compose `TopAppBar`, since Compose widgets react to theme changes.